# How to Improve this query for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select SUM(count.counts),  CountMostUtilizedApps
from 
( (select count(*) from  performance.apps WHERE  start_date >= '2021-02-06 00:00:00'  
   AND  start_date <= '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and dh.parent_id in ('1234','8910') and group_id in ('4567','1112') group by crashes order by crashes desc limit 5) counts
  (select count(*)  from  performance.apps WHERE  start_date >= '2021-02-06 00:00:00' 
   AND    start_date <= '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and parent_id in ('1234','8910') and group_id in ('4567','1112') order by AppTime limit 10) CountMostUtilizedApps 
    
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is to properly write code, even if this is SQL script and ask question in question content, not only in title.

Like in following refcatored SQL query (from yours question):

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(count.counts)
    ,CountMostUtilizedApps
FROM
SELECT
    SUM(count.counts)
    ,CountMostUtilizedApps
FROM
    ( 
        (
        SELECT count(*) from  performance.apps 
        WHERE
                start_date >= '2021-02-06 00:00:00'  
            AND start_date <= '2021-02-09 00:00:00'
            AND dh.parent_id IN ('1234','8910')
            AND group_id IN ('4567','1112')
        GROUP BY
            crashes 
        ORDER BY
            crashes desc limit 5
        ) counts
        (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM 
            performance.apps 
        WHERE
                start_date >= '2021-02-06 00:00:00' 
            AND start_date <= '2021-02-09 00:00:00'
            AND parent_id IN ('1234','8910')
            AND group_id IN ('4567','1112')
        ORDER BY
            AppTime limit 10
        ) CountMostUtilizedApps 
    )
```

Asking: `How to Improve this following query for PostgreSQL ?`

Is not enough. Be more specific. What you exactly mean ?

I'm not PostgreSQL expert, and more important thing as any other here you must to give more details, because nobody here do not know what your database contains .

As I said I'm not PostgreSQL expert but for my first look your's SQL Query should'nt works at all...Isn't it true ?

Comment: Yes, it was not working. I was unable to make it work. I am new to Postgres was trying different ways to make it work. Thanks for your help.